# Redirect 301 with query string without a trailing slash?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a rule in my htaccess file setup like so:

```
Redirect 301 /sale https://example.com/art/?sale=1
```

This results in the URL redirecting to `https://example.com/art/?sale=1/`, whereas I want the URL to be `https://example.com/art/?sale=1`

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have other rules also?

Comment: I managed to just work around the code with the trailing slash, there are other rules (WordPress based). The trouble occurred when I tried to access $_GET['sale'], it returned as "1/" when it should just be "1".